# Best / Easiest recommended approach for news feed vertical column menu in Orchard

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

i'm new to Orchard but very impressed with it. I've been trying to find an easy way to have a vertical column based menu in Orchard. Because there is a lot of features and options i'm reluctant to take the wrong approach. I'd like to go in the right direction on this one by asking the experts

I just want an image (to the left) and short paragraph to the right. This repeating downwards just like many popular newspaper websites

Exactly like what http://www.dailymail.co.uk/home/index.html has at the right of the page...

Many thanks for the advice, Kind REgards, J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to solve this by adding these fields to blog post:

- media picker field (I tend to call this field "Teaser image") used to select picture that will be shown in the news feed
- text field (I tend to call this field "Lead") with Html flavor used to add short text paragraph, or lead, that will be shown in the feed

Afterwards, you can, either

- add Recent blog posts widget to the zone where you wish your news feed to display or
- create a Query that will return posts you want to be shown in the feed and then add Projection widget to the zone where you want to display your feed

You can see the similar design I created for the [Croatian NATO portal](http://www.nato.hr) with some extra fields in the design. It's in Croatian language, but it'll serve the purpose of showing what you can do with Orchard for your news-portal style web site.